# invalid multibyte character crashes when script is loaded from source (umlauts / special characters)

Tags: r, special-characters, ggplot2, sweave

EDIT:

Thx to suggestions from the mailing list I realized that the problem I got has nothing to do with Sweave or Latex. It´s some Mac OS X related issue. Whenever I run my script by selecting all and sending it to R it works.

When I use

```
source("myplainRcode.R")
```

i get the error message stated below

---

finally I got sweave working together with ggplot2 on my Mac OS X. I invoke Sweave inside R with

```
Sweave("myfile.Rnw")
```

which creates the desired latex output. Now that the basic tests work, I try to source my real world file and it crashes at the following line:

```
 gl_bybranch = ddply(new_wans,.(period,Branchen),
 function(X)data.frame(Geschäftslage=mean(X$sentiment)))
```

I guess it has either to do with the ".(period...)" or the "ä" . Unfortunately I can't change these labels because they are also used in legends. So, somewhere in my code these ugly umlauts will appear. Is there a way to escape them in Sweave? I can't believe that this is problem since Sweave is written by a German who probably have second most umlaut characters (behind Turkey).

The error message I get is: invalid multibyte character in Parser on line 195

Thx for any ideas in advance!

Comment: Does it crash when you source it as part of normal `.r` file, or only when it's part of a Sweave file? And does it crash when you run it interactively?

Comment: the script works fine if I just run it in R (interactively) . But hell, you helped a lot. It does crash when I just source it, no matter if I use Sweave... Did not think of that, but don't understand it either. If I mark everything and run it, it works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

YAY ! i got it. Sorry for the noise everybody.  I switched all three files (.Rnw, mysource.R , invokeSweave.R) to UTF-8 it finally worked. So everybody who works with Komodo on a Mac make sure to change your default encoding to UTF-8 !