# Error: invalid multibyte character in parser at line 1 and stop

Tags: r

Described as title, R stopped with the following error message:

> Error: invalid multibyte character in parser at line 1

Usually, the error message emerges intermittently during R usage and it's hard to pin point the cause. Sometimes it pops up when I turn to R (using Rstudio) and the process stops.

I have tried reinstalling R, Rstudio, JDK maybe 5 times... to no avail.

[image]

Comment: Have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3307544/invalid-multibyte-character-crashes-when-script-is-loaded-from-source-umlauts

Comment: I got this error and eventually found out that I had "smart quotes" in my code thanks to copying and pasting from code sent to me in Slack that wasn't in a code block. Apparently Slack prettified it for us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try updating your RStudio via "Tools" -> "Check for Package Updates", as shown in the screenshot below，and you may solve your problem.

[image: screenshot]

Answer (score 11):

```
source("Function.R", encoding="utf-8")
```

Comment: although it is likely to be an encoding issue, given the question it seems unlikely that a source command is going to fix the user issues and unless the user has some familiarity with what "encodings" are is is unlikely he would ever gain anything from reading your answer. Perhaps you could elaborate in your answer or in a comment to the question why you think it has to do with "encodings" and perhaps give some pointers to fix his in R studio.

Comment: Another options is to put `options(encoding = "latin1")` at the top of the script R

Answer (score 1):

Please use 0.98 verion even though this version has a little problem with Data Viewer. https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/206569407-Older-Versions-of-RStudio. This is the known problem as posted by Josée Martens https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/rropen/o8Xhjo0Zes0/P8C0Wb56CAAJ

Answer (score 1):

1. tool->global option ->code->saving-> default text encoding:UTF-8
2. use library(KoNLP)
3. rewrite r script without Korean

I succeed step no.3

Answer (score 0):

For me I was installing a package locally from source, and for me it worked to

- Extract the `tar.gz` file
- Open and re-save all the files with encoding utf-8 (using sublime text)
- Install the package again using the following command

```
install.packages("/home/path_to_package/extracted_package_folder", repos=NULL, type="source")
```

My exact error message was:

```
Error in parse(outFile) :
  invalid multibyte character in parser at line 137
```